# using "{0} of {1}" in a ToString

Tags: c#, string, format

Printing out a deck of cards I have a tostring in my class that reads

```
public override string ToString(){
  return GetCard() + " of " + GetSuit();}//end ToString
```

but I want all of the results to be in even columns so I tried

```
public override string ToString(){
  return "{0,5}of{1}",GetCard(),GetSuit();}//end ToString
```

and I don't think I can do that and I get an error. Is there another way to modify a tostring so I make even columns?

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: you probably need String.Format here

Comment: `public override string ToString() => $"{GetCard(),5} of {GetSuit}";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, probably, are looking for *string interpolation*:

```
 public override string ToString() => $"{GetCard(),5} of {GetSuit}";
```

please, note the *syntax*: `$` before the interpolated atring and values in *braces* `"...{value}..."`

Comment: Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score 1):

solved using

````
public override string ToString(){
return $"{GetCard(),-2} of {GetSuit()}";}//end ToString```
````